# What is this ratio: expected returns on stock divided by risk free rate?

Tags: interest-rates, brownian-motion, continuous-time

So this ratio has come up in some work I'm doing and I can't seem to figure out if it is attested in the literature.  Here's the setting:

Given a risk free rate $r(t)$ and a stock price which follows a geometric brownian motion, $\frac{dS(t)}{S(t)} = \mu_S(t)dt + \sigma_S(t)dW(t)$, what is the significance/definition/terminology for the ratio of expected growth in stock prices to the risk free rate, $\frac{\mu_S(t)}{r(t)}$?  This is more of a question regarding vocabulary/interpretation, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this useful, particularly in a world of interest rates around par (0)?

Comment: I'm not sure interest rates will remain so low forever.  But I'm just curious if anyone knows of the significance of this ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it makes sense to refer to [CAPM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model): it is expected that stock return is proportional to market excess return and it beta
$$ \mu_S(t) = r(t) + \beta_S\cdot(r_m(t)-r(t)).$$ Where $r_m(t)$ is market expected return and $\beta_S$ is stock beta.

Thus according to CAPM it's expected that $\frac{\mu_S(t)}{r(t)} = 1+\beta_S\cdot(\frac{r_m(t)}{r(t)}-1).$

Comment: Hmmm... this only works in a world with many stock, but what about in a model with a single risky asset?

Comment: Then I don't have an answer in this case.